# Can't use a new created derived column in same spark sql code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have creating a new column in using "AS" statement in pyspark-sql code

```
accounts_2.price - COALESCE(cast(accounts_2.price as Numeric(38,8)), 0)  AS follow_on_price
```

As you see here I am creating a new column "**follow_on_price**

but when I am trying to use this newly created column in my same spark sql code

```
, accounts_2.unlock_price - COALESCE(cast(accounts_2.upfront_price as Numeric(38,8)), 0)  AS follow_on_price
, follow_on_price * exchange_rate_usd AS follow_on_price_usd
```

It does not recognise the **follow_on_price** used immediately in the same spark SQL so when I create a new **temp view** and use it as new table for the next step then its able to do the same . Please explain why so? Why can't spark Sql take the new column reference from the same spark code so that I don't have to create an extra step for **"follow_on_price * exchange_rate_usd AS follow_on_price_usd"** and it can be done in  single step. like we do in normal sql like Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

it's SQL standard behavior, to prevents ambiguities in query. we cannot reference column aliases in the same  SELECT list.

you can use inner query instead like below

```
>>> data2 = [{"COL_A": 'A',"COL_B": "B","price":212891928.90},{"COL_A": "A1","COL_B": "cndmmkdssac","price":9496943.4593},{"COL_A": 'A',"COL_B": "cndds","price":4634609.6994}]
>>> df=spark.createDataFrame(data2)

>>> df.show()
+-----+-----------+-------------+
|COL_A|      COL_B|        price|
+-----+-----------+-------------+
|    A|          B|2.128919289E8|
|   A1|cndmmkdssac| 9496943.4593|
|    A|      cndds| 4634609.6994|
+-----+-----------+-------------+

>>> df.registerTempTable("accounts_2")

>>> spark.sql("select s1.follow_on_price, s1.follow_on_price*70 as follow_on_price_usd from (select COALESCE(accounts_2.price)  AS follow_on_price from accounts_2) s1")
+---------------+-------------------+
|follow_on_price|follow_on_price_usd|
+---------------+-------------------+
|  2.128919289E8|    1.4902435023E10|
|   9496943.4593|    6.64786042151E8|
|   4634609.6994|    3.24422678958E8|
```